# error comes like this Invalid row number (65536) outside allowable range (0..65535) while im using .xlxs format

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx

i'm tried 3 type of formats .xls,.xlxs,.xls.

my aim is getting a values from the query and  display  output as a xls file.

my code is :

```
      filename = "file.xlxs";

      workbook = new HSSFWorkbook()

      sheet1 = workbook.createSheet("All Files");

      rs=stmt.executeQuery("select slno from files");

      while (rs.next()){
        i++;
        HSSFRow row = sheet1.createRow((int)y);
        cell = row.createCell((short)0);
        cell.setCellValue(rs.getString("slno"));
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

     }
```

i'm getting error like this:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid row number (65536) outside allowable range (0..65535)

my query slno have contain above 96000 numbers

Comment: A `Excel` sheet of binary type `*.xls` has only 65536 rows max. So works as designed.

Answer (score 2):

Naming the file `.xlxs` doesn't change the fact that `HSSFWorkbook` uses the format of `.xls` files.

If you wanted to write an `.xlsx` (not `.xlxs`) file, which doesn't have that row count restriction, use `XSSFWorkbook`.

Just like the [**documentation**](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/) says:

> **HSSF** is the POI Project's pure Java implementation of the Excel '97(-2007) file format. **XSSF** is the POI Project's pure Java implementation of the Excel 2007 OOXML **(.xlsx)** file format.